# Find a general formula for $c_{n+1}=c_n+\frac1{c_n}$ (Recursive)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, elementary-number-theory

Find a general formula for $c_{n+1}$

If $c_1 = 1$ and $$c_{n+1} = c_n + \frac{1}{c_n}$$

$$c_1 = 1$$

$$c_2 = 1 + 1 = \frac{2}{1}$$

$$c_3 = 2 + 1/2 = \frac{5}{2}$$

$$c_4 = \frac{5}{2} + \frac{2}{5} = \frac{29}{10}$$

$$c_5 = \frac{29}{10} + \frac{10}{29} = \frac{941}{290}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A073833) is [always a good idea](http://oeis.org/A073834).

Comment: It doesnt show an explicit formula though? (+1)

Comment: True, but this does tell you that an explicit formula is probably not known to anyone.